# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.state.Place.trim') in react native

Tags: forms, react-native, validation

I am new to react native. I have created a form. thats working fine. But now I storing some values as default values in form input fields .(I am getting this value from server)
I am storing as default like this

```
onChangeText={this.handlePlace} value = {this.state.Place} defaultValue={placeD}  />
```

and I am getting data from server like this

```
 const placeD = data.retail_information_data[0] ? data.retail_information_data[0].name_of_place : ''
```

and on submit I am checking input vaidations like this

```
if (!this.state.Place.trim()) 
  {
    this.setState({ PlaceError: 'Field Should Not Be An Empty' })
    //alert(this.props.route.params.ltn2)
    return;
  }
```

Now the problem is when user logout and come again in that form. then Lets say user want to edit only one value like name. but in my case when I edit only one value and then submit form its throwing error like this

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.state.LegalName.trim') in react native
```

and form will only submit when I change all values. But I want that if user will change only one value then also form have to be submitted.

Comment: What are you getting in console for `this.state.LegalName` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can't just set the default on the form without setting the same value for the state variable since you are checking it in your validation code. For example:

```
const placeD = data.retail_information_data[0] ? data.retail_information_data[0].name_of_place : ''
this.setState({ Place: placeD })
```

you will need to do this for all fields in your form.